# My popup javascript code can not pass ID or session in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I used pop up in buttons using above code in asp.net. every thing works fine and the pop up open with it's controls.but there is a big problem! I passed IDs and sessions in each buttons and as i use this cod all my asp code did not execute because the Css code execute first and by "onclientclick" code it retired to another page and asp behind code won't execute any more. can any body help me to execute my asp.net behind code before "onclientclick" code?
thanks:
here is my javascript code:

```
 function pop_up(url) {
        newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=517,width=885,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,titlebar=no,left=400,top=120');
        if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
        return false;
    }
```

for the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" 
                                                                                                        CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
                                                                                                        Height="25px"  
                                                                                                        oncommand="Button2_Command" Text="Submission details" Width="180px" 
                                                                                                        Font-Size="9pt"  OnClientClick="return pop_up('CompleteInfo.aspx')" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", "pop_up('CompleteInfo.aspx');", true);
```

in your button click after assigning session etc. and remove OnClientClick property of button.

Comment: it works... you are great. but for the first time fire fox didn't let pop up come up. Is it natural or not?